# Differences between sudo and su in inheriting environment

Tags: sudo, environment-variables, su

1. Why can the command run by `sudo` inherit the environment from the
   parent shell process, while the shell process after `sudo su` to the
   root user doesn't?

   ```
   t@ocean:/tmp$ export ME=tim
   t@ocean:/tmp$ sudo echo $ME
   tim

   t@ocean:/tmp$ sudo su
   root@ocean:/tmp# echo $ME

   root@ocean:/tmp# exit
   ```
2. Is the environment inherited from parent to child processes?
3. Is the shell process after `sudo su` to the root user a child process of the previous user's shell process?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The variable expansion is performed by your interactive shell. You're running the command `sudo` with the arguments `echo` and `tim`. If you want the expansion to happen in the shell invoked by `sudo`, tell it to run a shell and pass the string `echo $ME` to that shell:

   ```
   sudo sh -c 'echo $ME'
   ```

   `sudo` removes most variables from the environment, because they can be a security risk in some circumstances. See the manual and your machine's configuration for details. With typical configurations, the variable `ME` would be removed from the environment, so `sudo sh -c 'echo $ME'` would print nothing.
2. The environment of a process is a copy of its parent, unless the parent decided to change it. (More precisely, the environment is passed to [`execve`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/execve.html); most programs just pass through whatever they had.) Sudo is one of the programs that decides to change the environment.
3. If you run `sudo su`, that runs a shell (because you didn't pass a command to `su`). The parent of that shell process is the process that invoked `sudo`, i.e. the shell where you ran the command `sudo su`.

Answer (score 6):

The environment variable expansion is done by the shell so the command you're actually running is "sudo echo tim".  This is all done before sudo is run.